# EWS : how to get notification when meeting starts/end in exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have to do some operation when meeting starts and end. But i not able to find anyway to get the notification from EWS when meeting starts and end.

I tried push subscribe and subscribe for folder ID "calendar" and then do GetItem to fetch the meeting information. But the problem with this approach is i have to store all meeting item with timing and have my logic(timer) to find when meeting is started and finished.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but I happened across it and thought someone might still find an answer useful.

EWS notifications will not be of use in this case - the notifications that you can subscribe to only alert you to new mail, deleted, modified, moved, copied, and created items. There's nothing built in regarding notifications for start times of meetings.

So what I'd suggest is that you use the EWS FindItem operation with a CalendarView element to get all calendar items that occur for the next N hours, to determine what appointments are happening that day, and then create your own logic/timer to perform your operation at the appropriate time. Hope that helps.